# 'unresolved import error' for public function in a module

Tags: rust

In my rust project directory, I have a src/main.rs.

```
fn main() {
    
    use crate::server::launch_server;
    launch_server(); // error

    ....
}
```

I have a directory src/server, which contains mod.rs and server.rs:

mod.rs

```
pub mod server;
```

server.rs:

```
pub fn launch_server() {...}
```

So server module is defined and it contains a public function launch_server.

But I see error:

```
unresolved import `crate::server::launch_server`
```

What am I missing in my setup?

Comment: Do you have `mod server` in `main.rs`? Also, it needs to be `crate::server::server::launch_server`.

Comment: Yes, 'pub mod server' is in main.rs. And you are right, adding extra server worked. But its seems very strange. I want to put all my server code in server directory.

Comment: You have two `server` (`server/server.rs`), so you need two `server`. If you want one, put the code in `server/mod.rs` or in `server.rs`.

Comment: Or re-export your server/server.rs in server/mod.rs to flatten one level of modules to callers, while keeping your private code structure the same. Then `crate::server::server::launch_server` can become `crate::server::launch_server` for users of your crate (including your own code)